# mongod crashed without logging

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu-12.04, pymongo

I'm using mongodb v2.2.2 on single server(Ubuntu 12.04).

It crashed with no log on /var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log.
It seemed crashed during logging.(Character is interrupted. And, this log is normal query log.)

And, I checked on syslog about memory-issue(for example, `killed proccess`),
but couldn't find it.

Then, I found the following error on mongo-shell(db.printCollectionStats() command).

DLLConnectionResultData
{
  "ns" : "UserData.DLLConnectionResultData",
  "count" : 8215398,
  "size" : 4831306500,
  "avgObjSize" : 588.0794211065611,
  "errmsg" : "exception: assertion src/mongo/db/database.cpp:300",
  "code" : 0,
  "ok" : 0
}

How do I figure out problems?

Thank you,

Comment: seems to be a memory error. Is the mongod version 32 bit or 64-bit?

Comment: Thank you for comments. I'm using 64bit version of mongod.

Comment: could you pls check whether u can able to find any errors in server log?And if u enable journaling pls disable and try

Comment: Thanks arunb2w. I checked not only mongodb.log and syslog but also kern.log,dmesg.But, could not find any errors on them. Unfortunately, I was set the log level to 1 at that time. Is `Journaling` related to this or other problem?(I'm using Journaling anytime.)

Answer (score 0):

I checked that line in the source code for 2.2.2 (see [here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/v2.2/src/mongo/db/database.cpp#L300) for reference).  That error is specifically related to enforcing [quotas](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#quota) on MongoDB.  You haven't mentioned enforcing quotas here or what you have set the files limit to (default is 8) but you could be running into the limit here.

First, I would recommend getting onto a more recent version of 2.2 (and upgrading to 2.4 eventually, but definitely 2.2.7+ initially).  If you are using quotas, [this fix](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-9497) which went into 2.2.5 would log quota exceeded messages (previously logged only at log level 1, default is log level 0).  Hence if a quota violation is the culprit here, you may get an early warning.

If that is the root cause, then you have a couple of options:

1. After upgrading to the latest version of 2.2, of the issue happens repeatedly, file a bug report for the crash on 2.2
2. Upgrade to 2.4, verify that the issue still occurs, and file a bug (or add to the above report for 2.2)

In either case, turning off quotas in the interim would be the obvious way to prevent the crash.

Comment: Thank you for answering, Adam C. I'm not using quota limits. I'm checking around quota/allocation right now.